# Stop slide at last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here is the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bddzZm)

I have created custom slider using jQuery.

I want it to stop at the last slide.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var slideCount = $('.billAddress .addressBlock').length
  var outerWidth = slideCount * 273
  $('.billAddressCnt').css({
    width: outerWidth,
    left: 0
  })
 })

var i = 0;
$('.nextBillAddress').click(function(){   
   i++
   var leftMove = 273*i
   $('.billAddressCnt').animate({
     left : -leftMove
   })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `sliderPosition` variable and decrease it every time you move slider. When it is 0 or 1 (based on what you want) - stop sliding. The code will be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var slideCount = $('.billAddress .addressBlock').length
    var sliderPosition = slideCount
    var outerWidth = slideCount * 273
    $('.billAddressCnt').css({
      width: outerWidth,
      left: 0
    })
})

var i = 0;
$('.nextBillAddress').click(function(){   
    i++
    if (sliderPosition == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    sliderPosition--;
    var leftMove = 273*i
    $('.billAddressCnt').animate({
        left : -leftMove
   })
})
```

There is also a possibility to do things using more advanced way like creating slider object, implement counter and slider there.

Comment: @zik if this code snippet is working for you then please accept the answer :)

Comment: @munjal your code works but it calls the event handler after the last element reached. the best way is to remove the handler.

Comment: @OmarElawady :) that was not my answer. I was suggesting to zik for accepting the answer,if that answer was working for him :)

Comment: I'm commenting on the answer not the comment :)

Answer (score 0):

unbind the event haandler when reaches the last div.
add this line to the first of your function.

```
if(i + 1 === $('.addressBlock').length) $('.nextBillAddress').unbind( "click", arguments.callee );
```